# Sending javascript array to php Yii page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I want to pass JavaScript array to PHP using ajax.
the status in Network is 200 and everything is ok but i got erorr
Here is the code.
data is array:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url: '?r=site/mahsulat',
     dataType: "json",
        data : JSON.stringify({ 
        'arra' :arr
    }),

    success :  function(data) {
        alert(data);
      window.location = '?r=site/mahsulat' 
    },
    error : function (data){
        alert('Error');
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what is the error?

Comment: i'm gettin error alert

Comment: console.log the data in the error callback

Comment: you mean :
error : function (data){
            console.log(data)  ;  
        }

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Comment: i got long object

Comment: do you have a controller?

Comment: Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/jqXHR.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/jqXHR.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/jqXHR.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/jqXHR.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/jqXHR.abort(), state: .Deferred/promise.state(), always: .Deferred/promise.always(), then: .Deferred/promise.then(), 11 more… }

Comment: @VictorLuna yes i have

Comment: there should be a property "errorText", you can see the reason of the error there.

Comment: Can you please share the code from the controller? If your controller is managing the action from the call you can maybe find what your controller is getting and returning from the ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to `stringify` your object.
just send your object without `stringify` that.

Comment: damet garm dadash